# Using Bundle products in two different cases in the same site

Tags: product, event-observer, bundled-product

I am developing a site which has many products that are going to be collections of individual books.
So we have a collection A and that collection must have an SKU and be made of 4-5 individual simple products. These collections when they belong to one category(let's say category A) they should be with fixed quantities.I mean if you buy collection A you are buying one copy of the individual products.
My idea is to do that with bundle products.So far so good.

The problem is that for the same collections i want the customer to be able to choose the quantity of each individual product if that collection is on a different category(let's say category B).

So i want to use the bundle products in both cases but in case one with fixed quantity and in the second the user will be able to change the quantity.(By the way i use a module in order to be able to change the quantity). 
Can i use an observer for example when the product is loaded to change the template of the product or hiding the quantity? Is this a bad approach? Any other idea is welcome.
Thanks in advance and i hope it make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Create two bundle products each (or create once, then duplicate) and set "User Defined Qty" to "Yes" in the first and to "No" in the second. No custom code needed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think, by adding a custom attribute in bundle product may solve your issue. Add an attribute with name 'quantity type'(example) in the bundle product. Make it as a dropdown  for select following options none/fixed/variable. You need to create two bundle products then. One should be set with 'fixed'(for category A) and other should be set to 'variable'(for category B). For bundle product which not depend on this custom attribute. you can set it to 'none'.

Now for category A, you should filter product with 'quatity_type' attribute which is set to the value 'fixed'. For category B, bundle product with 'variable' value should display.